# Is NuGet metapackage reserved to .net core only?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

In the .NET doc, I see a lot of explanations around nuget metapackages, bu all the samples are with .NET Core. Is it possible to create metapackage for full .net framework assemblies and consume this with a .net framework app?

Will it be possible only with ProjectReference and not with packages.config?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve ? Also, not sure if it relates to your question, but ".NET Standard" target was created for compatibility of projects using different .NET (core / non-core) versions.

Comment: No it's not related. I didn't test to reference a metapackage from a full .net project so I was asking myself if it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

A metapackage is just a package that doesn't contain any content/libraries of its own and has dependencies to all the other packages that it encompasses. This isn't something specific to NuGet, by the way, many package managers have the same concept and usually call them meta packages too.

About NuGet specifically, since NuGet has to deal with different target frameworks and asset selection, which many package managers don't have to worry about, it might be necessary to put some fake information in the nupkg to make it work properly. What I think I've seen before is to create an empty file named `_._` in the `lib\target framework` folders that match the TFMs that the dependant packages use. For example, if you create a metapackage for packages that have libs for net45 and netstandard2.0, then you'd have two files in the nupkg, `lib/net45/_._` and `lib/netstandard2.0/_._`, both are empty. However, I haven't tested this myself, so you should, but just in case a nupkg with only a nuspec and nothing else doesn't work, try this.

Since meta packages aren't otherwise special (they have the same package type as "regular" packages), they work just fine with both packages.config and PackageReference. Meta packages are perhaps most useful for PackageReference, because it supports transitive dependencies. In other words, the user adds the metapackage, their csproj gets one reference and is otherwise "clean". With packages.config, when they add the metapackage, all of the transitive dependencies will also get added to packages.config and csproj.

Comment: So if I understood well what you're saying, I sould be able to create and consume metapackages from full .net framework projects (not core) since it's only a nuget related thing. Isn't it?

Comment: short answer, yes, it should work fine. Long answer, .NET Core and .NET Standard are just TFMs. From NuGet's perspective, there's nothing particularly special about them, other than asset selection or TFM compatibility is more complicated. You can target .NET Framework with SDK projects as well, although they're limited to PackageReference for NuGet packages. But, you can use PackageReference with old style csproj as well. So, you seem to be under the impression that .NET Core is somehow different or special, but it's not, it's just that a bunch of new build tools came out at the same time.